# Angular2 data binding for Dynamically created mutl select html element

Tags: angular, data-binding, multiple-select, ngmodel

I am having issue binding multi select html element to the ngModel. When i am submitting the form i am getting only one selected labels out of multiple selected labels. I need a way to bind all selected values and return those values when form is submitted

I have tried the below scenarios

1)

```
<select multiple ([ngModel])="multiSelect1" ngControl="multiSelect1" (change)="multiSelect1=setSelected($event)">
                            <option value="1" id="1">Value1</option>
                            <option value="2" id="2">Value2</option>
                            <option value="3" id="3">Value3</option>
                            <option value="4" id="4">Value4</option>
                        </select>

setSelected($event): String{
    console.log($event.target.selectedOptions);
    let  values = [].slice.call($event.target.selectedOptions).map(a => a.value);

    return values.toString();
}
```

In above code even change event is being triggered the multiSelect1 is not getting updated. I am getting output as **2** when i am submitting the form

2) Here i have not used any change still getting the same output. Only the first option of the selected labels are being displayed

```
<select multiple ([ngModel])="multiSelect1" ngControl="multiSelect1">
                            <option value="1" id="1">Value1</option>
                            <option value="2" id="2">Value2</option>
                            <option value="3" id="3">Value3</option>
                            <option value="4" id="4">Value4</option>
                        </select>
```

Using Angular Version **2.0.0-beta.15**

I want to know if setSelected returns any value will that value get binds to the ngModel but it is not getting binded.

I am looking a way to bind and get all selected options in post when form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

there is no multi select default support in angular 2 yet as I heard, for work around this refer this

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

you can use prime ng Multiselect as an alternate which has complete component with binding , getter setter etc
here you can see the example for the same

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

Comment: Does prime ng work for Angular Version 2.0.0-beta.15??

Comment: yes offcourse, but for that you have to use components of primeng of beta 15 compatible. as of now primeng is also according to angular2 latest relese.

Comment: for Rc.1 primeng components here https://github.com/PardeepJain/primeng